# Pop values from user stack inside interrupt handler

Tags: pointers, gcc, assembly, osdev, pintos

I'm trying to implement a handler for system calls in Pintos. Before the interrupt is raised the arguments for the system calls are pushed in the following way:

```
/* Invokes syscall NUMBER, passing argument ARG0, and returns the
   return value as an `int'. */
#define syscall1(NUMBER, ARG0)                                           \
        ({                                                               \
          int retval;                                                    \
          asm volatile                                                   \
            ("pushl %[arg0]; pushl %[number]; int $0x30; addl $8, %%esp" \
               : "=a" (retval)                                           \
               : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                                  \
                 [arg0] "g" (ARG0)                                       \
               : "memory");                                              \
          retval;                                                        \
        })

/* Invokes syscall NUMBER, passing arguments ARG0 and ARG1, and
   returns the return value as an `int'. */
#define syscall2(NUMBER, ARG0, ARG1)                            \
        ({                                                      \
          int retval;                                           \
          asm volatile                                          \
            ("pushl %[arg1]; pushl %[arg0]; "                   \
             "pushl %[number]; int $0x30; addl $12, %%esp"      \
               : "=a" (retval)                                  \
               : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                         \
                 [arg0] "g" (ARG0),                             \
                 [arg1] "g" (ARG1)                              \
               : "memory");                                     \
          retval;                                               \
        })

/* Invokes syscall NUMBER, passing arguments ARG0, ARG1, and
   ARG2, and returns the return value as an `int'. */
#define syscall3(NUMBER, ARG0, ARG1, ARG2)                      \
        ({                                                      \
          int retval;                                           \
          asm volatile                                          \
            ("pushl %[arg2]; pushl %[arg1]; pushl %[arg0]; "    \
             "pushl %[number]; int $0x30; addl $16, %%esp"      \
               : "=a" (retval)                                  \
               : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                         \
                 [arg0] "g" (ARG0),                             \
                 [arg1] "g" (ARG1),                             \
                 [arg2] "g" (ARG2)                              \
               : "memory");                                     \
          retval;                                               \
        })
```

I have available a struct which contains all the registers that were pushed, but also a pointer to the user-level stack (onto which the system call number and the arguments were pushed).

```
/* Interrupt stack frame. */
struct intr_frame
  {
    /* Pushed by intr_entry in intr-stubs.S.
       These are the interrupted task's saved registers. */
    uint32_t edi;               /* Saved EDI. */
    uint32_t esi;               /* Saved ESI. */
    uint32_t ebp;               /* Saved EBP. */
    uint32_t esp_dummy;         /* Not used. */
    uint32_t ebx;               /* Saved EBX. */
    uint32_t edx;               /* Saved EDX. */
    uint32_t ecx;               /* Saved ECX. */
    uint32_t eax;               /* Saved EAX. */
    uint16_t gs, :16;           /* Saved GS segment register. */
    uint16_t fs, :16;           /* Saved FS segment register. */
    uint16_t es, :16;           /* Saved ES segment register. */
    uint16_t ds, :16;           /* Saved DS segment register. */

    /* Pushed by intrNN_stub in intr-stubs.S. */
    uint32_t vec_no;            /* Interrupt vector number. */

    /* Sometimes pushed by the CPU,
       otherwise for consistency pushed as 0 by intrNN_stub.
       The CPU puts it just under `eip', but we move it here. */
    uint32_t error_code;        /* Error code. */

    /* Pushed by intrNN_stub in intr-stubs.S.
       This frame pointer eases interpretation of backtraces. */
    void *frame_pointer;        /* Saved EBP (frame pointer). */

    /* Pushed by the CPU.
       These are the interrupted task's saved registers. */
    void (*eip) (void);         /* Next instruction to execute. */
    uint16_t cs, :16;           /* Code segment for eip. */
    uint32_t eflags;            /* Saved CPU flags. */
    void *esp;                  /* Saved stack pointer. */
    uint16_t ss, :16;           /* Data segment for esp. */
  };
```

I now want to get these arguments. All the pointers on the stack are 4-byte in size, so I thought that I could simply cast an argument (the dereferenced pointer) to the corresponding type, then increase the stack pointer by 4 and cast the next pointer.

I have the following question:

The pushl instruction pushes values onto the stack correct? So I should be able to get those values simply by de-referencing the pointer to the stack? E.g to get the first argument (assuming this is an int) I would use (int) *(f->esp + 4), where f is a pointer to a struct intr_frame and I add 4 because the system call number is the first element on the stack. Now the problem is that pointer arithmetic on void pointers is not allowed in C and the arguments can be of different type, so can anybody give any suggestions on how to pop these arguments from the stack?

Comment: Your code is broken because `g` constraint allows for `esp` relative operands which would be obviously wrong due to your `push` instructions changing `esp` before all the operands are processed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get the parameter values by dereferencing the user esp. Just as with any void *, you must cast it to a suitable pointer type before dereferencing it or indexing it. In this case, uint32_t  * would be appropriate, so you would use

```
 *(((uint32_t *)f->esp) + 1)
```

Note the +1 instead of +4, since the index is scaled by the size of the object pointed to. If you want to use the actual byte offset, you would need two casts

```
*(uint32_t *)(((uint8_t *)f->esp) + 4)
```

Comment: Blindly dereferencing a pointer provided by unprivileged user code would be a security hole.

Comment: @Timothy, yes, good point—the user code could have loaded anything into esp before the system call.